# Desktop Navigation Menu, How to fix the problem when you click?

Tags: oracle-apex

help please, I can not understand what the problem is. When you click on the drop-down menu, opens a completely different tab, which is located above.
[image]

The page itself opens correct.
But the menu unfolds is not correct.

What i want to see
[image]

Any thoughts? Maybe this is done in the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit the Menu you go into Shared Components-Navigation Menu.
Not sure what your problem is, but it could be something to do with how those are sorted.

What you need is for all the top layer tobs(the ones you have w/o names) to have no parent, and each have its contained tabs marked with it as parent.

And maybe try changing their sequence so that all the second layer tabs are in sequence between the top layer tabs(say your first top layer tab is sequence 1000, and your second top layer tab is 2000, make sure all the second layer tabs belonging to the first top layer tab are marked with the correct parent entry, and are numbered between 1000 and 2000).

I hope this resolves whatever bug you have.

Comment: Thanks for the help, solved the problem by re-creating the page.